# Decide Appearance Screen iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, screen, segue

please refer image below :

[image]

I want to start app 'directly' on "VIEW 1" screen or "VIEW 2" screen, without visual appearance of "START" screen which decide VIEW screen to display.

```
    Eg.  in loadView() of STARTviewcontroller.m 

 if (some condition)
    {
    call "VIEW 1" screen
    }
    else
    {
    call "VIEW 2" screen
    }
```

Is this best way to do it ?
what should i use segue / [self presentViewController: ...] ??

Comment: You can do that in app delegate's `didFinishLaunching` method. However, you wouldn't be able to navigate to either `view1` or `view2` because your `StartViewController` isn't embedded in a `UINavigationController`.

Comment: thanks @Adeel , it tried what you said [ viewdidload of "VIEW" controller it called] , but its opens "START" view as storyboard arrow point to "START" view.

Comment: You are right. What I suggested wasn't the complete solution. That was part of the solution and you would have not achieved what you desire without that.

Comment: Can you explain when do you want to show `StartViewController`?

Comment: i wished to use StartViewController to decide which VIEWcontroller to use... VIEW1 or VIEW2..

Comment: @Adeel can you give proper solution to call any VIEWcontroller from app delegate.. i have tried Code given below but it dint worked.. `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil]; ViewController *yourController1= (ViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view1"]; [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:yourController1 animated:YES completion:nil]; return YES; } `

Comment: Please try my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do one thing.

Set "**View1**" controller as initial view controller in your storyboard.

[image]

Now And in your **didFinishLaunch** of **AppDelegate**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    BOOL showSecondViewController = YES;
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    if (showSecondViewController) {

        ViewController2 *objSecondViewController = [mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];
        self.window.rootViewController = objSecondViewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


    } else {

        // It will show First view controller
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

You need to set IDs repectively for both viewControllers.
Then Determine which ViewController to present at AppDelegate level.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    if(someCondition)
    {
        UIViewController *yourController1= (UIViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"viewController1Identifier"];
       [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController: yourController1animated:YES completion:nil];
    }else{
       //instantiate 2ndViewController
       `enter code here`
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @gontse, i made changes as you said

Comment: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    ViewController *yourController1= (ViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view1"];
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:yourController1 animated:YES completion:nil];
    
    return YES;
}

Comment: but it opens in view controller where arrow points, i.e on "START" screen..

Comment: @nikange_me: you can instantiate the viewController(1 or 2) on StartViewController class : ViewDidLoad  I think be the perfect place to instantiate your controller then add viewController thereof as a child to startViewController

Answer (score 0):

From our discussion in the comments what I could understand is that you don't need to use `StartViewController` at all. First make the `View1` your `Initial View Controller` in the storyboard. And then just do this in your `AppDelegate`.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    BOOL someCondition;

    if (someCondition) {

        return YES;
    }
    else {

        UIWindow *keyWindow = application.keyWindow;
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = keyWindow.rootViewController.storyboard;
        ViewController2 *viewController2 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View2"];
        keyWindow.rootViewController = viewController2;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Did you change the `Initial View Controller` in your storyboard?

Comment: Yes, i made intialviewcontroller / pointed arrow to "view2" and trying to call "view1" in app delegate using code you posted.

Comment: Use break point and see how does the if statement executes. How are you checking the `someCondition`?

Comment: As of now, i am not checking for any condition. Direct using `UIWindow *keyWindow = application.keyWindow;
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = keyWindow.rootViewController.storyboard;
        ViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view1"];
        keyWindow.rootViewController = viewController;` in didfinshlauchwithoption

Comment: after using some breakpoint , i understood that our code that calls `VIEWcontroller` is executed first and then code of `Initial View Controller` , which shows 'Initial View Controller' screen,

Comment: The problem is in your code that you have posted in your previous comment. You are instantiating `View1` so it will always show you view1.

Comment: dont worry, @adeel. while executing i corrected it :) , it posted mistakenly..  but code works as of now ..     `    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        
    UIWindow *keyWindow = application.keyWindow;
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = keyWindow.rootViewController.storyboard;
    ViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view1"];
    keyWindow.rootViewController = viewController;
    });`

Comment: did it resolve the problem or you are still facing it. I'm afraid either I'm not understanding you correctly or you not communicating your problem right.

Comment: I am still facing problem as i am see VIEW1 first and then VIEW2,                                            current scenario : arrow points to VIEW1 and Code is as below

Comment: '
        if (someCondition) {
            
            return YES;
        }
        else {
            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                
                UIWindow *keyWindow = application.keyWindow;
                UIStoryboard *storyboard = keyWindow.rootViewController.storyboard;
                ViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view2"];
                keyWindow.rootViewController = viewController;
            });
        }'