# Call Storyboard scene from app delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate, scene

I want to call a storyboard scene `[storyboard ID : MyScene]` from appDelegate,

I've searched and tried many answer given on stack overflow!! but could not find working solution.

**One of the code I tried,**

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
UIViewController *sc= (UIViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyScene"];

[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:sc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Where you write this code, try using some delay

Comment: Check that "Main" is actually existing and you are not getting nil value in mainStoryboard.

Comment: thanks for reply @Wolverine , i wrote this in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions of app delegate..

Comment: try using call this code with some delay. dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Your code for presenting
});

Comment: Thanks @mohsin, "Main" storyboard exist.

Comment: @Wolverine, it worked !! Do we have other solution for, as i will be using the  "SCENE" as my first screen of app from set of  "SCENE's".

Comment: yes. there is concept of Containerview. in Which you can show 2nd view controller's view in 1st viewController.

Comment: or make your "SCENE" as a rootController, and when you finish showing diff screens/ images in sliding then you can switch the root controller as per your need.

Comment: I have added m comment as an answer, you can mark as correct, so if any other developer having the same issue, he/she can get help from this. Thanks.

Comment: @Wolverine can you help with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40124945/decide-appearance-screen-ios

Comment: I have give an answer. Try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using call this code with some delay.

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 

// Your code for presenting 

UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
UIViewController *sc= (UIViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyScene"];

[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:sc animated:YES completion:nil];

});
```